# Embossed Business Cards

Tags: print-design, texture

I'm about to do a run of business cards (90 x 55mm)and I'm hoping for it to be printed and the texture embossed.

The image attached is going to be printed, but wondering if there is any way of actually getting the texture to be embossed and how I would go about setting up the print file.

I've seen references on the web doing this technique but unsure of the printing process: http://www.designer-daily.com/stunning-3d-embossed-business-cards-54973

I've experimented by separating the image into two colours (black / white) 
– the white layer being embossed to create the texture. Is there any way of simplifying the white layer further as I would obviously have to turn it into vector for embossing.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Business Card Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8JbK.jpg)

Comment: The cards were produced by [Jukebox Print,](http://www.jukeboxprint.com/) and they have details on [how to supply files for 3D embossing here.](http://support.jukeboxprint.com/hc/en-us/articles/202322543-Design-considerations-for-Embossing-and-3D-Emboss)

Comment: As Lightcraft mentioned,  any  time you have a question about printing, you should ask your printer.

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY way to find out how to set this up is to talk to your printer, as there are many different ways to do embossing / debossing.

USUALLY for normal 2d embossing, a plain colour or vector should be supplied as a layer, this is then converted to a tool for processing.
HOWEVER the rather impressive example you included would have to be pressed in a die, which may need a 3d model creating, or a B&W image implying depth.

so in short.... ask your printer!